# subscribe to ko.observableArray() that contains member ko.observable()

Tags: knockout.js

I am building my view model dynamically from data sent from the server, and has been simplified for this example.

Alongside my main form i plan to run a summary form which would loop through all the available observables and do something with the data.

I have used a ko.observableArray() thinking it would be an easy place to dump all the member observables, and just subscribe to changes.

**My problem is the subscription is never fired. Any ideas what i am doing wrong please?**

*Please note i am open to other solutions, as long as my summary view model can be notified of when the selected values (which are built dynamically so length and names will vary) have changed that is fine it doesn't matter to me what technique is used.*

**Code and [fiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/XSqL4/7/)**

```
var createUserViewModel = function(names)
{
    var model = {};

    var length = names.length;

    model.selectedValues = ko.observableArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        model[names[i]] = ko.observable();
        model.selectedValues.push(model[names[i]]);
    }    
    return model;
}

var createSummaryViewModel = function(userViewModel){
        userViewModel.selectedValues.subscribe(function(newValue){
        console.log("yeah something has changed!");
        // loop through values here to get currently selected objects
    });
}

var createMasterVm = function(names){
    var self = this;
    self.userViewModel = ko.observable(createUserViewModel(a));
    self.summaryViewModel = ko.observable(createSummaryViewModel(self.userViewModel()));
    return self;
}

var a = new Array();
a.push("name");
a.push("age");
a.push("street");

ko.applyBindings(createMasterVm(a));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea with the dynamic parameters. I think I've got a great solution for you...a little bit of rework and you've now got something that's even more dynamic than your original fiddle ::

http://jsfiddle.net/XSqL4/10/

One of the main things to pay attention to is the generalization made that reduced the necessary objects down to just a ViewModel object for your whole model and then one smaller one to emulate the key/value pairs you're throwing in.

```
var NameValuePair = function (name){
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.value = ko.observable();
}
```

Also, your mark-up is totally dynamic now...

```
<!-- ko foreach: selectedValues -->
<p>
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label> 
    <input data-bind="value: value" />
    <label data-bind="text: value"></label>
</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this works out for ya...good little micro project for pushing unknown key-value pairs.

Comment: thanks @beauXjames your code was helpful and enabled me to make good progeess on my actual code. I have hit a roadblock on this and would appreciate your eyes on the code with the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500414/build-knockout-model-and-view-dynamically-radio-buttons-not-being-set

Comment: looks like you found the answers!