# Build radio button view dynamically, checked binding is not working using ko.observable

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, radio-button

This is my first question, pardon for any mistakes in posting the question.

My question might looks exactly similar to 
[Build knockout model and view dynamically, radio buttons not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500414/build-knockout-model-and-view-dynamically-radio-buttons-not-being-set)

From my research, the above question comes very close to my problem, but still could not get a fix.

In my requirement, for each question there are multiple radio buttons as choices and also there are prev and next navigation buttons. 
The question and choices are dynamically built,  the choice the user has made on the question is not being captured in the viewmodel property *self.current_question.response*.

Below is **snippet** of my view

```
<div id="questionpage" data-role="page" data-theme="c">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
      <h1>Question <span data-bind="text: current_question().queNo"></span></h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <!-- inputs -->
    <div id="inputs" data-role="content" data-theme="c">    
      <a id="prevbtn" href="#question" data-icon="arrow-l" data-bind="click: $root.prev, visible: hasPrev()" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Prev</a>
      <a id="nextbtn" href="#question" data-icon="arrow-r" data-bind="click: $root.next, visible: hasNext()" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Next</a>     
      <a id="completebtn" href="#question" data-icon="check" data-bind="click: $root.submit, visible: !hasNext()" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Submit</a>

      <p data-bind="text: current_question().queText"></p>
      <div id="inputdiv">
      </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->    
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Below is my **snippet** of my Viewmodel

```
// Question response object

    function QuestionResponse(stuId, examQueId,selAns)
    {
        var self=this;
        self.Student__c=stuId;
        self.Exam_Question__c=examQueId;
        self.Selected_Answer__c=selAns;
    }

    // Question object
    function Question()
    { 
        var self=this;
        self.response=ko.observable('');
        self.options=ko.observableArray();
    }

    function Question(id, queNo, queText, response, queChA, queChB, queChC, queChD, queChE)
    {
        var self=this;
        self.id=id;
        self.queNo=queNo;
        self.queText=queText;
        self.response=ko.observable(response);
        self.options=ko.observableArray();
        //self.checked=ko.observableArray();

        // helper function to add an option
        self.addOption = function(option)
        {
            if (null!=option)
            {
                self.options().push(option);
            }
        }

        self.addOption(queChA);
        self.addOption(queChB);
        self.addOption(queChC);
        self.addOption(queChD);
        self.addOption(queChE);
    }

    function ExamViewModel()
    {
        var self=this;

        // initialise variables to default observables
        // self.question_response=ko.observable(new QuestionResponse());
        self.current_question=ko.observable(new Question());
        self.current_question_no=0;
        self.email=ko.observable('Your email id');
        self.questions=ko.observableArray();
        self.studentId;

        self.errorMsg=ko.observable('');
        self.completeMsg=ko.observable('');
        self.hasPrevious=ko.observable();
        self.hasNext=ko.observable(false);
        self.hasPrev=ko.observable(false);

        // function executed when the user clicks the 'next' button
        self.next=function()
        {
            $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "a", text: "Loading", textVisible: true });

            // advance to the next question
            self.current_question_no++;
            self.current_question(self.questions()[self.current_question_no]());

            // setup previous/next buttons
            self.hasPrev(true);
            self.hasNext(self.current_question_no<self.questions().length-1);

            // add the input markup
            self.addInput();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        }

        // function executed when the user clicks the 'prev' button - could refactor
        // some of this and the next function into a common helper
        self.prev=function()
        {
            $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "a", text: "Loading", textVisible: true });
            //alert('in prev '+self.current_question().response);
            self.current_question_no--;
            self.current_question(self.questions()[self.current_question_no]());
            self.hasPrev(self.current_question_no!=0);
            self.hasNext(true);
            self.addInput();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        }

        // callback for the JavaScript remoting call    
        self.responseCB=function(record, event)
        {
            if ( (!event) || (event.status) ) 
            {
                $.each(record,
                        function()
                        {
                            var question=new ko.observable(new Question(
                                                            this.Id, this.Exam_Question_Number__c, this.Question__r.Question_Text__c,'', 
                                                            this.Question__r.ChoiceA__c, this.Question__r.ChoiceB__c, this.Question__r.ChoiceC__c,
                                                            this.Question__r.ChoiceD__c,this.Question__r.ChoiceE__c));

                            self.questions.push(question);

                            // if the current question is empty, set it to this question 
                            if (typeof self.current_question().queText === 'undefined')
                            {
                                self.current_question(question());
                            }
                        });

                // setup whether to display the next button                             
                if (self.questions().length>1)
                {
                    self.hasNext(true);
                }

                // add the input markup
                self.addInput();
            }
            else if (event.type === 'exception')
            {
                self.error(event.message);
            }
        }

        // add the appropriate input markup
        self.addInput=function()
        {
            self.addRadioInput();

        }


        self.addRadioInput=function()
        {
            $('#inputdiv').html(
                '<div id="radio" data-bind="value: $root.current_question.response">' +
                '   <fieldset id="radiocontrol" data-role="controlgroup">' + 
                '       <' +  // Visualforce will break the comment that encloses the containerless element, so split over two lines
                '!-- ko foreach: current_question().options --> ' +
                '       <input name="radio-options" type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $root.current_question.response, attr: {id:\'rb_\' + $index() }"></input> ' +
                '       <label data-bind="attr:{for : \'rb_\' + $index() }, text: $data"></label> ' + 
                '       <' + 
                '!-- /ko --> ' +
                '   </fieldset> ' +
                '</div> ');

            // bind the new markup to the viewmodel
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#radio')[0]);

            // trigger JQM to enhance the newly created radio button div
            $('#radio').trigger('create');
        }


    }
```

Have tried multiple options, but could not get what's wrong with my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you're using jQuery in your viewmodel, which means that you're not modeling your view properly. Without seeing your radiobutton HTML and bindings, we can't see why you're not getting your selected value set.

Comment: The radio button HTML is dynamically built in the viewmodel function self.addRadioInput and the HTML div tag where the radio button is inserted is `<div id="inputdiv"> </div>`. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Inserting code via jQuery is the wrong way to do things. Knockout can handle dynamically creating elements. Your bindings on the radio button seem appropriate for setting `response`.

Comment: Why do you have a `value` binding on `div#radio`?

Comment: Yes there is no need for `value` binding on `div#radio`, but I am trying the approach you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div#inputdiv` should look something like this, which will handle displaying radio buttons appropriately so that you don't have to resort to injecting DOM elements with jQuery. My logic might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you can adjust as appropriate.

The `with` binding will only render its contents if its variable is populated. Variables in the div will refer to the variable's members.
The `jqm` binding is a custom binding handler you would need to write (or find).

```
<div id="inputdiv" data-bind="with:$root.current_question">
  <div id="radio" data-bind="jqm: true">
    <fieldset id="radiocontrol" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach:options">
      <input name="radio-options" type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: response, attr: {id:'rb_' + $index() }" />
      <label data-bind="attr:{for: 'rb_' + $index() }, text: $data"></label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your jqm binding handler might be as simple as this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqm = {
  init: function (el) {
    $(el).create();
  }
};
```

That's at least worth a shot. Also take a look at [this article](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/10/23/integrating-knockout-and-jquerymobile.html), and maybe google around for jqm and knockout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you just knocked down my problem.To the first question you have asked why I was using jQuery to build my view, it is because I got to know from my research that JQM enhancement would not work once the page is loaded. And now though the responses are getting captured, the question and choices have lost the JQM enhancement. I assume your suggestion to use `jqm` custom binding is to address the same issue, given my little understanding about custom `ko` custom binders could you point me the best resource which would help me ?

Comment: Thanks Roy, of course I need some help on the `jqm' custom binding but you have fixed the issue in my original question, I am accepting yours as the best answer.

Comment: @Lakshmi See my updated answer for some pointers on jqm. If you can't get it to work, ask another question.